# How to Ignore all .scss files from SonarQube scanner?

Tags: sonarqube, styles, code-coverage

SonarScanner scans all styles files, causing lower down my coverage report.
I want to ignore all `.scss` files with the help of `sonar-project.properties` file.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sonar.coverage.exclusions` property.

```
sonar.coverage.exclusions=*.scss
```

The above example overwrites value set on the server, so it is recommended to just add this extension to extensions list in SonarQube UI (`Administration → Configuration → General Settings`). We use the following list:

[image: extensions list]